# May a Jew deliver non-Kosher food to another Jew?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, technology, shlichus-agency

With the increase in usage of food delivery services such as instacart or uber eats many people now have their food delivered to them. I would like to know if any contemporary authorities discuss the permissibility (or lack thereof) of serving as a driver for any of these food delivery companies if one run into the possibility of delivering non-Kosher food items to a Jew and thereby assisting in another's transgression. I am also curious if the driver would have the status of a messenger of the company or of the customer in this scenario.

Comment: "I am also curious if the driver would have the status of a messenger of the company or of the customer in this scenario." What is the difference?

Comment: do you see the driver as subject to different rules from a Jewish waiter serving non-kosher food?

Comment: I would assume its lifnei iver